# How to generate elements of IEnumerable One by One

Tags: c#, .net, linq, deferred-execution

Suppose I have an `IEnumerable<Thing> enumerable` object and that each `Thing` in this list is expensive to generate.

When I go to execute the following code there is considerable overhead when the code reaches line 1, because, as I understand it, the entire list is generated right there before beginning iteration.

```
foreach (Thing t in enumerable)   // line 1
{                                 // line 2
    DoStuffWith(t);               // line 3
}
```

Is there a way to generate each `Thing` only as needed? Like this

```
while(enumerable.HasMoreThings())
{
    var e = enumerable.GenerateNextThing();
    DoStuffWith(e);
}
```

Original code:

```
using (var db = new PolyPrintEntities())
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    IEnumerable<NotificationDto> notifications = db.EmailServiceNotifications
        .Select(not => new NotificationDto
        {
            Notification_ID = not.Notification_ID,
            StoredProcedure = not.StoredProcedure,
            SubjectLine = not.SubjectLine,
            BodyPreface = not.BodyPreface,
            Frequency = not.Frequency,
            TakesDateRange = not.TakesDateRange,
            DateRangeIntervalHours = not.DateRangeIntervalHours,
            TakesAssociateId = not.TakesAssociateId,
            NotificationType = not.NotificationType,
            Associates = not.SubscriptionEvent.SubscriptionSubscribers
                .Select(ss => new AssociateDto
                {
                    Record_Number = ss.Associate.Record_Number,
                    Name = ss.Associate.Name,
                    Email = ss.Associate.EMail
                })
        });

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Enumeration:{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); //about .5 seconds
    sw.Reset();

    sw.Start();

    // List is generated here, this is where lag happens. 
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var n in notifications)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Generation:{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); //about 10 seconds
            i++;
        }

        var ret = n.GetEmails();
        db.EmailQueues.AddRange(ret);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: "the entire list is generated right there before beginning iteration." that's precisely what the `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` interfaces avoid. You got it backwards

Comment: To add on to what Camilo said, `while (enumerable.MoveNext())` is what happens under the hood when you iterate over an enumerable. We need to see more of your code - the problem must be elsewhere. (What is creating the list? Are you using `yield`?)

Comment: The enumerable is coming from a Linq Statement that is reducing the size of a query to a database through an entity framework. I timed the block of code which creates the IEnumerable, and the portion of the foreach loop which creates just the first object. I've amended my post to include the code which lead me to write this question

Comment: We need to see the  most important part: `//List is generated here, this is where lag happens.`

Comment: That's just a comment, there's no code there. That's just a comment which is what I think is happening when the for each Loop is entered

Comment: @TylerGabb ok what does `GetEmails()` do?

Comment: @TylerGabb Also, if you already figured it out you can post a self answer.  Just don't pretend to be someone else.  Just say I figured it out and describe why.

Comment: @maccettura O.K. sorry about that, I wasn't sure what the convention was. But now I know, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Simply [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) them.

```
while(enumerable.HasMoreThings()) 
{
    yield return enumerable.GenerateNextThing();
}
```

Each time someone want next item (caller of this function perhaps) this function will create and *yield* items lazily.

Answer (score 2):

Foreach is a c# language construct that gets turned into something very similar to your second code section. IEnumerable was designed to do exactly what want, it will give 1 item at a time only when you need it

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

It appears that after further refining mycode I have obtained some empirical data which disagrees with what i thought was going on.

I  used the sw to measure time in a different way:

```
        using (var db = new PolyPrintEntities())
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            IEnumerable<NotificationDto> notifications = db.EmailServiceNotifications
                .Select(not => new NotificationDto
                {
                    Notification_ID = not.Notification_ID,
                    StoredProcedure = not.StoredProcedure,
                    SubjectLine = not.SubjectLine,
                    BodyPreface = not.BodyPreface,
                    Frequency = not.Frequency,
                    TakesDateRange = not.TakesDateRange,
                    DateRangeIntervalHours = not.DateRangeIntervalHours,
                    TakesAssociateId = not.TakesAssociateId,
                    NotificationType = not.NotificationType,
                    Associates = not.SubscriptionEvent.SubscriptionSubscribers
                        .Select(ss => new AssociateDto
                        {
                            Record_Number = ss.Associate.Record_Number,
                            Name = ss.Associate.Name,
                            Email = ss.Associate.EMail
                        })

                });



            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Enumeration:{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); //about .5 seconds
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            //Each item appears to be generated One by One 
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var n in notifications)
            {
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"Generation_{i}:{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); //about 1 second
                var ret = n.GetEmails();
                db.EmailQueues.AddRange(ret);
                sw.Start();
                i++;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

and the output:

```
Enumeration:404
Generation_0:985
Generation_1:986
Generation_2:986
```

So it appears that what I thought I needed to do, I was in fact already doing.

I took care to make the data coming back from the database as non uniform as possible, as to avoid obtaining erroneous data.

Comment: Yeah but, I wanted to stay in the spirit of stack overflow. I just thought that's how you answer your own question